# Generate a <table> of a database table in Play 2.3.x

Tags: html, postgresql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Is it possible to use one of Play's [html.helper's](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/views/html/helper/package.html) to generate a HTML table of one's database table? Or any html type? I'd like to create a webview of my database (ideally one where I could edit the cells of the rows, though i'll take read-only) and I'm wondering if Play has anything built in to easily generate the HTML for a database table. Open to suggestions on how to do this as I didn't find much while googling.

Thanks in advance

Comment: no there is nothing like that to build your GUI.

Comment: No... Play does not provide anything to generate HTML for your DB tables. But in case you are talking about CRUD generation simimlar to Rails ... there is this module - https://github.com/hakandilek/play2-crud

Comment: Yeah I just discovered this last night and I think it might be what I was thinking (essentially just googling for the wrong terms). So for others who stumble across this, try googling "play2 crud"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the developer of the [play2-crud](https://github.com/hakandilek/play2-crud) module. I think this is what you're looking for, and it was my initial intention to solve described problem in the first place. If you have any questions about integration please feel free to ask. If you find any bugs or problems you can directly [create an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/hakandilek/play2-crud/issues/new).